# ubuntu 11.04 DNS issues

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wireless-networking, dns

I'm experiencing some issues involving my Ubuntu Server.

So far, I can connect to machines on my local network, but the server itself doesn't have internet. And since the each machine is routed through the server, no machine has internet either.

I can ping my nameserver, and I can ping any local machine. I just can't connect to the internet.

My resolve.conf looks like this:

```
nameserver    142.232.18.204
```

So I have a DNS, and all ethernet devices are connected. I've tried starting the network manager, restarting the machine, removing and adding the interfaces back to the `/etc/network/interaces` file, but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas? I'm pretty stuck right now.

EDIT:

My routing table looks like this:

```
Destination         Gateway          Genmask         Flags      MSS Window  irtt iface 
142.232.18.0        0.0.0.0          255.255.255.0   U          0   0       0    eth0
169.254.0.0         0.0.0.0          255.255.0.0     U          0   0       0    eth0
0.0.0.0             142.232.18.254   0.0.0.0         UG         0   0       0    eth0
```

Not sure if that helps any.

Comment: Can you ping external IPs? If you can access your name server, you are on the internet, it just sounds like you can't resolve addresses. Is your resolv.conf really like that? It should be on one line not two.

Comment: Nope, i can't ping any external IP's.

My `ifconfig` says that my machine has a local IP address of `142.232.18.2` if that helps with anything

Comment: Well, as I said, if your file is actually like what you've posted, there is a problem. The keyword and value need to be on the same line.

Comment: my mistake, the file appears as a single line.

I've also tried running `dig +trace www.google.com` but the only output is `Recieved 17 bytes from 142.232.18.204#53(142.232.18.204) in 0ms`

Comment: Can you `ping 142.232.18.254`. That is your default gateway. If you can not reach that then you have found your problem.

Comment: Hmm, turns out, i CAN'T ping my default gateway. Are there any solutions to that, or is that more of a IP issue?

Comment: By IP, i mean ISP*